# Product attribute not visible in admin , when creating configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I have created select type product attribute programmatically and set it source option custom from another model. it is working fine, options are visible in attribute detail. But when creating the configurable product then this attribute is not visible there.

I have set all possible options.

Comment: Does the attribute has also the following option values,  scope is set to global, attribute is visible and attribute is user defined?

Comment: If I will make attribute_is_user defined then how I will fetch my custom options, which I defined in different model